# Things that need to be done before an attempt to publish ios app to appstore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, app-store

I am trying to release an app on the App Store. According to Apple there are few things that need to be verified to ensure your app to be approved by apple. So I would like to know what are the things that I need to know or do with my app before I attempt to publish an ios app to the app store.

Answer (score 2):

This URL will give you complete information to "Add a New iOS or OS X App"

[To add a new iOS or OS X app](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/8_AddingNewApps/AddingNewApps.html)